# Adding new column based on SELECT from other table MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following Table in my Microsoft SQL database

**Monitors**

| monitor_id | is_active | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | false | fence_monitor |
| 1 | true | bycicle_monitor |
| 2 | true | car_monitor |

And one more which is the `Logger`

| monitor | count | time_stamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | 11/10/2021 15:10:00 |
| 1 | 5 | 11/20/2021 15:08:00 |
| 1 | 12 | 11/20/2021 15:11:00 |
| 1 | 8 | 11/10/2021 15:15:00 |

In the Logger table, the PK's are `monitor` and `time_stamp`.
where `monitor` is a foreign key to Monitor.monitor_id

Now I need to filter the unactive monitors which I do with the following statement:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Monitors
WHERE is_active = 1
```

I also have 3 queries to select the total count for example in the current **day** / **alltime** or in **current hour** on `monitor = 1`:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(count),0) AS total_day
FROM Logger
WHERE monitor = '1'
AND DATEPART(DAY, GETUTCDATE()) = DATEPART(DAY, time_stamp)
```

I also have for current hour but I think you get the idea.
My main question is, how would I combine these 4 statements (filter is_active, filter alltime count, filter daily count, filter hourly count) in order to get a table like this:

| monitor_name | alltime | today | current_hour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bycicle_monitor | 25 | 8 | 8 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to join the tables and use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT
  monitor_name  = m.name,
  alltime       = ISNULL(SUM(count), 0),
  today         = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN time_stamp >= CAST(CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS date) AS datetime)
                                   AND time_stamp < CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS date)) AS datetime)
                                  THEN count END), 0),
  current_hour  = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN time_stamp >= DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, '20000101', GETUTCDATE()), '20000101')
                                   AND time_stamp <  DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, '20000101', GETUTCDATE()) + 1, '20000101')
                                  THEN count END), 0)
FROM Monitors m
JOIN Logger l ON l.monitor = m.monitor_id
WHERE m.is_active = 1
GROUP BY
  m.name;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ec1dc9db776ec7ae90ad43392b29f7ee)

Comment: Any way to translate this to an LINQ statement ?

Comment: Yes of course, you just use `select new { grp.Count(l => l.timestamp >=...` or something like that. I suggest you make a *new* question for that